# Saving data from kafka to mysql using Golang

Tags: mysql, go, apache-kafka

I am faced with a problem. I am trying to consume data from kafaka and save it in mysql. The data I am trying to consume is a string and I want to split the string into different categories and save them in MySQL. I am using Golang as a programming language and Gorm as ORM for MySQL.

Here is what the model looks like

```
type Lagbaja struct {
    gorm.Model
    Level string
    Time time.Time
    Info string
    LogType string
    
}
```

This is the configuration I used for Kafka

```
package kafka

import(
    "github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    //"observability/db"
)

type Config struct {
    ConsumerConfigMap *kafka.ConfigMap
    DB *gorm.DB

}
```

So, here is where I am having issues

```
package kafka

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka"
    "gorm.io/driver/mysql"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "observability/db/entities"
    "log"
)



func SaveLogs(vlog *entities.VoyanceLog) {
    // refer https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#dsn-data-source-name for details
    dsn := "<YOUR_DATABASE_USERNAME>:<YOUR_DATABASE_PASSWORD>@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/<YOUR_DATABASE_NAME>?charset=utf8mb4&parseTime=True&loc=Local"
    db, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }

    db.Create(vlog)
}


func Flush(ctx context.Context, cfg Config) error {

    cnsm, err := kafka.NewConsumer(cfg.ConsumerConfigMap)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    topic := "voyance-logs"
    err = cnsm.Subscribe(topic, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    run := true
    for run == true {
        select {
        case <- ctx.Done():
            log.Println("caught cancellation from context, terminating")
            run = false
        default:
            ev := cnsm.Poll(100)
            if ev == nil {
                continue
            }

            switch e := ev.(type) {
            case *kafka.Message:
                err := processMessage(e)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Println("error while converting message to tweet: ", err.Error())
                    continue
                }
            case kafka.Error:
                // errors should be informational and the client will try to
                // recover, but halt if all brokers are down.
                log.Println("Error: ", e.Code(), e)
                if e.Code() == kafka.ErrAllBrokersDown {
                    run = false
                }
            default:
                log.Println("ignored...")
            }
        }
    }
    log.Println("closing consumer")
    cnsm.Close()
    return nil
}

func processMessage(msg *kafka.Message) {
    var vlog entities.VoyanceLog
    err := json.Unmarshal(msg.Value, &vlog)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    
    err = SaveLogs(&vlog)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if len(tags) > 0 {
        for _, tag := range tags {
            err := SaveLogs(vlog)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
            }
        }
    }
    log.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Saved logs: %s", vlog.Id))
    if msg.Headers != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%% Headers: %v\n", msg.Headers)
    }
    return nil
}
```

This is what I have I am unable to save into mysql and I am getting errors on these lines

```
switch e := ev.(type) {
                case *kafka.Message:
                    err := processMessage(e)
                    if err != nil {
                        log.Println("error while converting message to tweet: ", err.Error())
```

I am totally new to Golang and Kafka. What do you suggest I do please?

Comment: Suggestion: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use Kafka Connect, not Golang to write to a database.

Comment: I had difficulties usimg kafka connect, could you please give a real world project with kafka connect. I still need to use Golang for some other things

Comment: 1) What specific error are you getting with the code here? What is Lagbaja? How is that the same as VoyanceLog? 2) Kafka Connect is so simple, any blog you find is just as close to real world examples. You're more than welcome to use Golang to manipulate the Kafka data into a format that works with the JDBC connector, if that's the issue. Perhaps you can create a new post to clarify what issues you are having with it though?